# How to use ISAPI_rewrite to convert pretty URLs into query string URLs?

Tags: isapi-rewrite

In ISAPI_rewrite 3 documentation is this example

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?\.asp)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.+)? $1$4?$2=$3 [NC,LP,QSA]

http://www.example.com/foo.asp/a/A/b/B/c/C
http://www.example.org/foo.asp?a=A&b=B&c=C
```

Since my products can have more or less parameters in query string, this seemed like right approach. Based on given example I tried to create a rule for my case with no luck.

```
http://www.example.com/product-name.aspx/a/A/b/B/c/C
http://www.example.org/products.aspx?a=A&b=B&c=C
```

Answer (score 1):

After more digging I came up with solution. Seems like there is no other  way but using two rules.

```
  RewriteRule ^(.*?\.htm)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(.+)? $1$4?$2=$3 [NC,LP,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*?\.htm$ product.aspx [NC,L]
```